# Ranger filemanager defaulting to nano

Tags: linux, lua, awesome-wm, alacritty

I set Ranger as a keybind with Awesome Window Manager (AWM). My environmental variables and shell (ZSH) for both visual and editor are set to VIM. When I use the keybind (super + f), Ranger defaults the editor to Nano.
The man page for Ranger says that it defaults to VIM.
I have no idea why it is doing this.

'''
awful.key({ modkey }, "f", function () awful.util.spawn( "alacritty -e 'ranger'" ) end,
359         {description = "ranger" , group = "super"}),
'''
^^^This is the keybind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something probably set the `EDITOR` environment, somewhere. Follow these steps to fix it:

1. Open `/etc/passwd` and make sure your shell is `zsh`
2. Make sure you have `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim` in `~/.zshrc`
3. Replace `awful.util.spawn` with [awful.spawn.with_shell](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.spawn.html). This ensure it reads `~/.zshrc` instead of launching `range` with an "empty" environment.